# Can I use predict() to predict INDEPENDENT variable from dependent variable in a model?

Tags: r, model, prediction, predict

I have a growth rate model:

```
model <- nls(Length~a*exp(-b*exp(-c*Age)), data=df, start=list(a=160,b=0.5, c=0.1))

> summary(model)

Formula: Length ~ a * exp(-b * exp(-c * Age))

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a 173.03146   12.68100  13.645  < 2e-16 ***
b   0.54255    0.06118   8.868 9.94e-15 ***
c   0.13961    0.04195   3.328  0.00117 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13.73 on 117 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 12 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.693e-06
  (4 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

and I now want to apply this to a separate dataset, for which I have LENGTH data but not AGE. i.e. I want to predict age (my independent variable in the model) from length (dependent variable). Is this possible?

I would like predicted age to appear as a new column in my dataset so I have a corresponding predicted age for each measured length. I feel like this will be something like:

```
df2$age.predict <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(Length=df2$Length))
```

but I know this isn't right and I don't want to create a new dataframe/list I want it to appear as a column in my df2.

TIA

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72576514/edit) with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that, given your model, you can get the predicted value of `Age` given `Length` like this:

```r
df2$Age <- -log(log(173.03146 / df2$Length) / 0.54255) / 0.13961
```

**Explanation**

You didn't supply any sample data, but we don't really need it. Let's take the results of your regression:

```r
a <- 173.03146
b <-  0.54255
c <-  0.13961
```

Given your formula, we can predict `Length` for given values of `Age`

```r
Age <- 1:50

Length <- a * exp(-b * exp(-c * Age))
```

And we can see this gives reasonable-looking results:

```r
plot(Age, Length)
```

[image]

Now, to get `Age` given `Length`, the easiest thing to do is rearrange the formula so that it is in terms of `Age` (see footnote for the steps to do this in pseudocode)

```r
Predicted_Age <- -log(log(a / Length) / b) / c
```

If we have this right, then `Predicted_Age`, which was calculated only from `Length`, should be a vector of ages from 1 to 50:

```r
Predicted_Age
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> [26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Footnote - math steps to rearrange formula (pseudocode)**

```
Length == a*exp(-b*exp(-c*Age))            # Original formula
log(Length) == log(a) -b*exp(-c*Age)       # Take log of each side
log(Length) - log(a) == -b*exp(-c*Age)     # Subtract log(a) from each side
log(a) - log(Length) == b * exp(-c*Age)    # Negate both sides
log(a / Length) == b * exp(-c*Age)         # Simplify log on left
log(log(a / Length)) == log(b) - c * Age   # Take log of both sides
log(log(a / Length)) - log(b) == - c * Age # subtract log(b) from each side
log(log(a / Length) / b) == -c * Age       # Simplify left hand side
- log(log(a / Length) / b) / c = Age       # Divide both sides by -c
Age == -log(log(a / Length) / b) / c       # Swap left and right
```